# Profiles being created without foreign keys in related model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys

I have multiple user types defined in a single user model:

```
  enum role: { staff: 0, clinician: 1, admin: 2 }
```

Clinician users each have a clinician profile that is automatically created using after_create, and I'm intending to store the clinician_profile id on the users table. For some reason, when the clinician profiles are created, the clinician_profile_id remains null on the users table for all users, including clinician users. How do I fix that?

**module ClinicianUser**

```
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    belongs_to :clinician_profile
    has_many :lists
    has_many :universities, through: :lists
    has_many :dispatches
    has_many :referral_requests, through: :dispatches
    after_create :create_clinician_profile, if: :clinician?
    belongs_to :market
    validates :market_id, presence: true, if: :clinician?
  end

  class_methods do
    def create_clinician_profile
      self.clinician_profile.create!
    end

  end
end
```

**class ClinicianProfile < ApplicationRecord**

```
has_one :user, -> { where role: :clinician }
end
```

**Users table schema:**

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",                                       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                       null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "remember_digest"
    t.string   "activation_digest"
    t.boolean  "activated",                        default: false
    t.datetime "activated_at"
    t.string   "reset_digest"
    t.datetime "reset_sent_at"
    t.string   "encrypted_password",   limit: 128
    t.string   "confirmation_token",   limit: 128
    t.string   "remember_token",       limit: 128
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.integer  "role",                             default: 0
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.integer  "university_id"
    t.boolean  "approved",                         default: false
    t.integer  "market_id"
    t.integer  "clinician_profile_id"
    t.index ["clinician_profile_id"], name: "index_users_on_clinician_profile_id"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["market_id"], name: "index_users_on_market_id"
    t.index ["remember_token"], name: "index_users_on_remember_token"
```

Comment: Can you add the `create_clinician_profile` method?

Comment: I don't have an explicit method for it - It's currently being handled exclusively by this line in the clinician concern module: after_create :create_clinician_profile, if: :clinician?

Comment: Try explicitly creating a method `def create_clinician_profile; self.clinician_profile.create!; end`

Comment: I added the class method I created in the clinician concern to the original question - the users table still has all null values for clinician_profile_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class method shouldn't be used here to operate on a instance object.

You could use a callback block instead:

```
after_create do |user|
  ClinicianProfile.create(user: user) if clinician?
end
```

Furthermore the association is defined as a belong_to so the parent object can create the association too but that's just a personal opinion.